# Powershell Script via Task Scheduler Not Working with Arguments

Tags: arguments, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to automate  a daily password reminder to those employees whose password will be expiring within 14 days. The PowerShell script I wrote (NewPasswordChange.ps1) works flawlessly when I run it via PowerShell, but will not run when put into Task Scheduler. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

**Action:** Start a program
**Program/Script:** C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

**Add Arguments:** -File 'NewPasswordChange.ps1' -smtpServer 'COMPANY-com.mail.protection.outlook.com' -expireInDays '14' -from 'IT Support it_support@COMPANY.com' -Logging -LogPath 'c:\logFiles'

Comment: You are sending the mail parameters to powershell.exe, not to the script.

Comment: So, how would I fix it? The argument I used (Minus -File) is exactly what I use in PS to run the script manually.

Comment: It would probably be better to use the Send-MailMessage command in the PS script to send the email, then use -File to call only the script.

Answer (score 0):

Only powershell understands the single-quotes. When used from a regular command line `'IT Support it_support@COMPANY.com'` for example will be interpreted as 3 arguments:

1. `'IT`
2. `Support`
3. `it_support@COMPANY.com'`

Use double quotes instead:

```
-File "NewPasswordChange.ps1" -SmtpServer "COMPANY-com.mail.protection.outlook.com" -ExpireInDays 14 -From "IT Support it_support@COMPANY.com" -Logging -LogPath "c:\logFiles"
```